# Compile a project (say, Emacs) to LLVM bytecode

Tags: c, clang, llvm, bytecode

I cloned the Emacs source, with the intention of compiling to LLVM bytecode. I have been fiddling with Makefile flags for hours, but with no luck. Whenever I Google this, I get completely unrelated results about compiling `.el` files.

So I ask you this: how can I compile a project like Emacs to LLVM bytecode?

I am on OS X 10.9 Mavericks.

EDIT: I ran these commands:
`CC=clang CFLAGS=-emit-llvm ./configure --with-jpeg=no --with-gif=no --with-tiff=no`
then
`CC=clang CFLAGS=-emit-llvm make`

Then I got this error:

```
xml.c:23:10: fatal error: 'libxml/tree.h' file not found
#include <libxml/tree.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

When in fact libxml2 is already installed.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I have done that. I modified the `CFLAGS` to have `-emit-llvm` and got precisely 0 bytecode files. Also, your answer is completely unhelpful.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Pardon me. Other things compile fine with clang. I got bytecode, as expected, and could compile with, say, `emcc`.

Comment: The edit is a *huge* improvement. It looks like even though you've installed libxml, the compiler doesn't know about it (especially, where its headers have been installed). If memory serves, you specify such directories with `-I`, just like with gcc.

Comment: @JerryCoffin so it looks like even `CC=clang CFLAGS="-O4 -I/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.1/include/libxml2/libxml/tree.h" make` doesn't help find `libxml/tree.h`

Comment: And with `CC=clang CFLAGS="-O4 -I/usr/include/libxml2" make`

Comment: This is really about how to configure clang to build emacs. Personally, I'd try to do that in smaller steps. I'd start by getting emacs to build with gcc. Then work on substituting clang for gcc. Finally, deal with getting clang to emit llvm ir.

Comment: @JerryCoffin build fine with gcc for some stupid reason.

Comment: When it comes to Emacs, I don't think compilation is the big issue. It uses something called "dumping" to increase the startup speed. This means that it loads the binary, the loads tons of elisp packages, and then writes out the entire memory content to a file. If you want this to work with clang bytecode you would have to reimplement this dumper from scratch, I guess. (Note, I don't really know that much about clang bytecode.)

Comment: @Lindydancer ...what? why would I have to reimplement the dumper?

Comment: @tekknolagi, if you would compile to native code, then I guess that it should work more or less directly. However, you talked about compiling to "byte code", in which case I suspect that the existing dumper system doesn't work.

Comment: @Lindydancer we are not talking about Emacs directly

Comment: `-I` takes a directory as an argument, which is prepended to `#include`'s argument, so instead of `-I /usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.1/include/libxml2/libxml/tree.h`, try `-I /usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.1/include/libxml2`.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Alright, so I got it to compile, but no bytecode in sight.

Answer (score 1):

`-emit-llvm` only tells `clang` that you want any emitted assembly to be in LLVM IR. However, you still need to inform `clang` that you would like it to emit assembly to start with. This is done by using the `-S` flag. Additionally, to compile to LLVM bytecode, you need to use `llvm-as`. Lastly, you will have to do this for every single file, since AFAIK you cannot link LLVM bytecode files together, meaning that you will have many, many LLVM bytecode files.

Enough blabbering though, here's how you would do it for a given file (in the shell, not in the `makefile`, mind you):

```
$ clang -c foo.c -S -emit-llvm # additional options as necessary
$ llvm-as foo.s
$ ls
foo.bc foo.c foo.s
```

### Explanation:

```
$ clang -c foo.c
```

Compile `foo.c` by itself without linking.

```
$ clang -c foo.c -S
```

Generate assembly and, if no output file is specified, save the results in `foo.s`.

```
$ clang -c foo.c -S -emit-llvm
```

Generate LLVM IR instead of native assembly.

```
$ llvm-as foo.s
```

Assemble `foo.s` and, if no output file is specified, save the results in `foo.bc`.

### EDIT:

Apparently, this works too:

```
$ clang -c foo.c -emit-llvm -o foo.bc
```

The `-o foo.bc` above is because otherwise clang will output a `.o` file.

Comment: Actually `clang -c foo.c -emit-llvm` will output bytecode directly.

Comment: It might depend on clang version, but it works at least on 3.3. To get a bc extension, you'll have to add `-o foo.bc`, otherwise the file will be `a.out` (but BC nonetheless)

Comment: @dureuill odd. I got `foo.o` when I tested it without an output param. Don't forget the `-c` flag!

Comment: @haneefmubarak how would I change that for the Makefile?

Comment: @haneefmubarak if I set CFLAGS, the `configure` script complains about not making executables or cross compiling: http://i.imgur.com/h6ri57Z.png

Comment: @tekknolagi That because ***you can't link bitcode files***. In other words, using `CFLAGS` on the configure script may not be possible. Instead, you will likely have to edit the makefile by hand, or, worse yet, compile each file by hand or write a new makefile yourself.

Comment: @tekknolagi Also, on a side note, your theme is really cool. Is it an `oh-my-zsh` theme and if so which one? :)

Comment: @haneefmubarak can I compile to bitcode AND and object files so it can link?

Comment: @haneefmubarak it is indeed `oh-my-zsh`. i think it's `norm` with some modifications. I am also using Solarized for iTerm2

Comment: @tekknolagi If you'd like to edit the makefile so that you have two separate lines, one with `-emit-llvm` and one without, certainly.

Comment: @haneefmubarak is there any way to do that with environment variables? The generated Makefiles are thousands of lines long

Comment: @tekknolagi No, that's what I have been trying to point out. It's highly unlikely you will be able to mass-modify anything easily that will allow you to use the generated makefile. Perhaps choosing a much smaller project may be in order.

Comment: @haneefmubarak ah, I see. I succeeded (sort of) with Netcat